# Conversion of interface with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

Is it possible to convert JSON to Java bean interface that has interfaces as attributes? I have one implementation of every interface and these can be directly mapped to interfaces.

Example:

```
public interface MyMainClass {

    public MyInterfaceClass1 getMyInterfaceClass1();

}
```

Comment: could you rewrite your question? I really don't understand it

Comment: Probably duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629596/deserializing-an-abstract-class-in-gson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is impossible to say whether there are other implementations of the interface: classloaders are free to create new classes on demand.
2. <s>The answer is, use `@JsonDeserialize(as=YourImpl.class)`, see [Jackson JSON, Immutable Classes, and Interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345325/jackson-json-immutable-classes-and-interfaces)</s>
3. My bad, for GSON it's `.registerTypeAdapter(Node.class, new NodeDeserializer())` and [Deserializing an abstract class in Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629596/deserializing-an-abstract-class-in-gson)